# get data from website content depending on specific word

Tags: c#

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            string url = "http://www.internalcompanywebsite.com";
            string content = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
```

I need to get some data such as (weight value or date value) from the website content - in other way beside the weight word will be (weight number), using above code the string will contains the html code for the website, how can I convert the website content not the html to an array or table (if I can copy the website content and using for loop to create array?), that may allow me to obtain the exact data in the specific location,

I have done this in VBA Excel as below, and I am working to convert this project to C# application form.

```
Link = "URL;http://companyInternalWebsite.com/data=" &
Worksheets("Storage_Fees").Range("F6").Value

With Worksheets("NPTS").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Link, Destination:=Worksheets("NPTS").Range("A1"))

    .BackgroundQuery = False
    .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    .SaveData = True
End With

'create NPTS data in MyArray
For c = 0 To 12
    For r = 0 To 1000
        NPTSArray(r, c) = Worksheets("NPTS").Range("A1").Offset(r, c)
    Next r
Next c
```

thanks in advance,

Comment: You could use an HTML parsing library (Such as the [HTML Agility pack](https://html-agility-pack.net/)) to locate the HTML node that contains the information and then retrieve it.

Comment: An alternative would be just to use Regex to pull out the information you need from the raw html response.

Comment: If you dont want to use external Html Parsing library, it would be greet to post the html that you want to parse so we could provide some way to retrive the data from the html string

Comment: What I understand that we can't use same method in VBA, by copying the webpage content and convert it to table or array, as the html code always the same (page build up), it doesn't include the shipment tracking checkpoints (the data what I need)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the C# nuget package Html Agility Pack to parse the html into an object. If you get that far post another question if you still need help with how to use it.

http://davidgiard.com/2018/06/20/UsingHTMLAgilityPackToParseAWebPage.aspx